# syslog-ng support for postfix multi-line when using tls

Tags: ssl, postfix-mta, syslog-ng

I am trying to get syslog-ng to support postfix's multiple lines.
As I understand it, syslog-ng can use the " flags(no-multi-line)" config option, but it is either not working, or I am applying it incorrectly.

My configurations:

Client:

```
source s_src {
       system();
       internal();
};
filter f_mail { facility(mail) and not filter(f_debug); };
log { source(s_src); filter(f_mail); destination(d_mail); };
destination d_tls {
    tcp("logs.myserver.com" port(999)
    tls( ca_dir("/etc/syslog-ng/ssl/")) );
};

log {
 source(s_src);
 destination(d_tls);
 };
```

Server:

```
source s_tls {
        tcp(port(999)
        tls( key_file("/etc/syslog-ng/ssl/logs.key")
                cert_file("/etc/syslog-ng/ssl/logs.crt")
        peer_verify(optional-untrusted))
        flags(no-multi-line) # no worky
        );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

From [syslog documentations](http://www.balabit.com/sites/default/files/documents/syslog-ng-pe-4.0-guides/en/syslog-ng-pe-v4.0-guide-admin-en/html/reference_source_syslog.html):

no-multi-line: The no-multi-line flag disables line-breaking in the messages; the entire message is converted to a single line. Note that this happens only if the underlying transport method actually supports multi-line messages. Currently the syslog, udp, unix-dgram drivers support multi-line messages; other drivers, for example, the tcp driver **does not**.

Thus it is not clear how multi-line messages get to your server in the first place. As a workaround, you might put the flag into file parameter:

```
destination d_farm_cmtslog_debug {
   file("/var/log/cm/cmts.debug" flags(no-multi-line));
};
```